# Agile Toolkit Form submit not working

Tags: php, atk4, jobeet

I'm new in Agile toolkit. I was trying to create the project Jobeet. I create models job and category and the file generate.php whith SchemaGenerator class.
When I select model and press Generate SQL submit button doing nothing.
Also I saw that submit button not working.

I think miss something!

Comment: You need to describe more in hopes of getting an answer.  You are clearly having basic setup issues that are more specific than what you're said thus far.

Comment: I setup 2 model files job and category. I setup generate.php with schemagenerator. Everything works fine. SQL connection is ok basicAuth is ok. config file is ok. But submit button not working!

Comment: I havent do anything else I'm 3rd day in project tutorial.

Comment: I suggest to rather look at http://www.youtube.com/theagiletoolkit if you would like to follow tutorial, those are more up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Jobeet tutorial is currently out of date. While we work on bringing it up to date, you're welcome to look at our Youtube tutorials:

- http://youtube.com/theagiletoolkit

Answer (score 0):

Jobeet project was updated recently to match the newest version of ATK. Please, try it again and let us know about it.
Thanks!